# Will standing on a non-conductive surface with wet feet prevent grounding and therefore electrocution?

Tags: grounding

It is a well known fact that one should not handle electrical equipment in general and electrical home appliances in particular when barefoot, or when one's feet are wet (even when wearing flip-flops/crocs).

I was wondering, could one stand on a non-conductive surface to avoid the grounding / electrocution even when on'e feet are a little wet (say after the shower)? Perhaps a couple of newspapers? A rug?

Comment: Aside from the main question, I’d not be too sure that wetted newspapers won’t conduct too.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I'm not too sure too, though I'm not talking about being dripping wet, rather being barely wet (e.g. after the shower having dried with the towel but the crocs/flipflops still a little wet). Not enough to really wet the newspapers I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two examples you gave of non-conducting surfaces (newspapers and rugs) are both water absorbent. As soon as they get at all wet, the water in them provides a path for electricity.

Thus you are not safe from electrocution.

You say "only a little wet". Then you are in a gray area where you might wind up "only a little bit dead." Is it worth risking your life? No. Don't do it.

You would need to stand on an insulating surface that was impermeable to water and rated to handle the voltage you're exposed to. Even then you'd need to be concerned about puddles of water on the insulating floor surface making a path to ground (Say there's a puddle that is touching a drain pipe, metal radiator, or an electrical cord with an exposed earth ground connection.)

Comment: Thanks Duncan. What would constitute such a surface? Anything that could be found around the house or cheap to buy?

Comment: That I'd bet my life on? No. What is enough to be safe depends on the voltage. As Placeholder says in his answer, you're much better off preventing yourself from being exposed to live voltage in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* get electrocuted while fully insulated from the ground.

Power could flow through your body from one part of an electrical item to another.

(*I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS*)
For example, if you stood on a plastic chair (a very bad conductor), in perfectly dry conditions, and put your fingers into a *live* light socket (i.e. with the power on) you *will* get electrocuted with the power flowing through your fingers. If you touched the *live* power with fingers on either hand, you might die.
(*I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS*)

It is extremely dangerous for power to flow through your heart. That could happen by touching two different *live* parts of electrical equipment with two different parts f your body.

You might, for example, touch some part of your bathroom which is itself earthed, such as water pipes, a water-heated towel rail, a metal sink drain, etc, while touching a *live* part of a piece of electrical equipment.

Your homes electrical distribution board should detect power running to Earth, and switch off, but I DO NOT RECOMMEND YOU TRY THIS.

Summary: You can be hurt or killed without having a connection through your feet to ground.

However, consumer electrical equipment is designed to be safe to handle. They are either encased in plastic, or the case is connected to an electrical ground connection. When the case is connected to ground, and the equipment is *damaged*, the flow of power via the case should trip the fuse or the circuit breaker. This protection mechanism can trip even when you are not touching the equipment.

Hence I do not agree "*It is a well known fact* that one should not *handle* electrical equipment in general and electrical home appliances in particular when barefoot". *I do not believe it is a "well known fact" because it is not adequate and is misleading*. It is an **illusion of safety**.

The only time this might be true is when equipment is disassembled or broken (Edit: which is an extreme meaning of "handle"). The danger through feet is not significantly worse than through your hands/arms. Insulated boots *might* save your life, which would be great, but they might not. (Edit: Sitting on a metal framed chair might be as lethal). Assuming safety because of them, or because feet are not bare, is IMHO a dangerous assumption.

Comment: A plastic chair is a very good conductor?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson - Ooops! Thanks Chris, I've fixed that.

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying the main factor to consider is whether the appliance is safe to handle, not if you're bare-feet (or even wet). That makes sense. However my concern is specifically about plugging/unplugging the appliance from the outlet - is that a possible weak link, even provided that the appliance and the outlet are intact and in order?

Comment: I would not handle electrical plugs with wet hands/feet. Ever. Just don't do it. In the US at least, current electrical code requires that outlets close to a source of moisture (10ft?) be protected by a GFCI circuit, which is supposed to cut off the flow of electricity if there is a leak to earth ground, and they are supposed to do it fast enough to prevent a lethal shock. They are a backup, however, and would still not handle electrical plugs or appliances while wet. GFCI outlets do fail. I've replaced 3 or 4 in the 14 years I've lived in my current house. Any one of those could have killed.

Comment: @DuncanC- I *Strongly* agree. Don;t do it. Also CFGI (or RCD) is a backup. Plugging or unplugging with wet hands is a weak link. Clearly wet feet make things bad. However, many bath fittings like taps and sink drains are Earthed, so touching one with your other hand, leg, ..., might be fatal.

Comment: I am very new to electricity, and try to learn from internet, so please excuse me for my lack of knowledge in it. As @gbulmer wrote "*You can get electrocuted while fully insulated from the ground*", how its works? In some other article I have read that current can only pass through a closed path. So standing on a plastic chair, how would one get electric shock, if he is not touching any other thing which are connected to ground? or is it current go through body regardless its connected to ground or not via live wire, and that can kill us. I am confused. Any clarification will be great help.

Answer (score 1):

Given that people use speciality items, like gloves, to handle live wires directly ... I've personally seen 330 V (not sure of the exact voltage) being disconnected and reconnected live by hand.  It's *possible*, and is done every day by professionals. The equipment being used was fully tested by a special testing machine for pinholes that the human eye can't see, and the equipment had it's own carrying case (so there would be no damage in transit).  And also, special boots which had under gone the same techniques.

I'm not sure I'd classify newspapers and rugs as good insulators even when dry.  And do you know there are no conduction paths? even in your brand new Crocs? Have you tested them?  All it takes is one micron sized hole in the proper material to make it a bad day.

Comment: This equipment also usually insulates the person from the live equipment, rather than the person from earth. The barehand variety of live line work, which this resembles, is possible but it requires years of training and equipment completely designed for the purpose from the start. It's very rare in Europe even among professionals, though more common in the US.